# How to correct the output of my cash register program?

Tags: c++

Write a C++ program to count the cash in the drawer of a cash register.
You are to count the number of each denomination of bill in the drawer. 
Call a function to determine the amount of money in each denomination by accepting the denomination and number of bills and returning the amount. The function can also accept the number of each denomination of coin and the number of coins and return the amount.

Your program should write each denomination, the number of bills/coins, 
the dollar amount of each and the total amount of money in the drawer.

Write both to the screen and to an outdata. Format is:

```
Denomination    Number  Amount
------------------------------
.
.
.
.
.
.
.
------------------------------
Total           $
```

```cpp
int main() {

    setprecision (2);
    string d;
    int t;
    int tpenny;
    int tnickel;
    int tdime;
    int tquarter;
    int tone;
    int tfive;
    int tten;
    int ttwenty;
    int tfifty;
    int thundred;

    double penny;
    double nickel;
    double dime;
    double quarter;
    double one;
    double five;
    double ten;
    double twenty;
    double fifty;
    double hundred;

    cout << "Enter denomination and amount of bills/coins" << endl;
    cout << "(i.e. 'penny 5' = 0.05c, 'quarter 3' = 0.75c, 'twenty 2' = $40.00)" << endl;
    cout << "When all amounts have been entered, enter 'done'" << endl;

    while (d != "done") {

        double total = penny + nickel + dime + quarter + one + five + ten + twenty + hundred;

        cin >> d;

        if (d == "done") {

            cout << "Denomination     " << "Number     " << "Amount" << endl;
            cout << "-----------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Penny:             " << tpenny << "         " << "$" << penny << endl;
            cout << "Nickel:            " << tnickel << "         " << "$" << nickel << endl;
            cout << "Dime:              " << tdime << "         " << "$" << dime << endl;
            cout << "Quarter:           " << tquarter << "         " << "$" << quarter << endl;
            cout << "One:               " << tone << "         " << "$" << one << endl;
            cout << "Five:              " << tfive << "         " << "$" << five << endl;
            cout << "Ten:               " << tten << "         " << "$" << ten << endl;
            cout << "Twenty:            " << ttwenty << "         " << "$" << twenty << endl;
            cout << "Fifty:             " << tfifty << "         " << "$" << fifty << endl;
            cout << "Hundred:           " << thundred << "         " << "$" << hundred << endl;
            cout << "-----------------------------------" << endl;
            cout << "Total:                       " << "$" << total << endl;
        }
        else {

            cout << "Enter additional currency. (if done, type 'done')" << endl;

            cin >> t;

            if (d == "penny") {
                tpenny = t;
                penny = value (d, t);
            }
            if (d == "nickel") {
                tnickel = t;
                nickel = value (d, t);
            }
            if (d == "dime") {
                tdime = t;
                dime = value (d, t);
            }
            if (d == "quarter") {
                tquarter = t;
                quarter = value (d, t);
            }
            if (d == "one") {
                tone = t;
                one = value (d, t);
            }
            if (d == "five") {
                tfive = t;
                five = value (d, t);
            }
            if (d == "ten") {
                tten = t;
                ten = value (d, t);
            }
            if (d == "twenty") {
                ttwenty = t;
                twenty = value (d, t);
            }
            if (d == "fifty") {
                tfifty = t;
                fifty = value (d, t);
            }
            if (d == "hundred") {
                thundred = t;
                hundred = value (d, t);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The way I have my code written at the moment works, but only if a value is entered for each individual currency. For example, if I don't enter a value for five, my Amount is some crazy number and the default for Number is not 0.

Do you have any ideas for how to fix this? Also value is a function that reads a string and an int, (i.e. penny 5) and returns the monetary value.

Comment: This is a classic assignment used to teach you about floating point errors. Because you don't have to deal with fractions of a cent, I'd suggest refactoring your program to use integer cents instead of float or double dollars. This site has some basics on floating-point errors: http://0.30000000000000004.com/

Comment: Go forth and initialize thine variables to a safe initial value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried initializing all your declared variables to 0? Some languages/compiler sets make no attempt to think that you want a 0 value for new variables and you're going to get whatever is in that memory location from before.

Comment: Since the language is tagged as C++, I would change the some in *Some languages/compiler* to most.

Comment: Thank you. Idk why I didn't think to initialize the variables when I declared them, but now it works!